# what are my options if i want to implement dashboard like Tumblr or Instagram in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, dashboard

All I want to do is explore my options. I want to create an app that requires displaying card like cells. I'm familiar with tableviews and how you can customize them to show certain info and picture.

Comment: u can use tableviewCell to customize ur cell

Comment: Depending on your skill level, you could always create your own class that supports this.  No exploration necessary when you go full custom.  Just a scroll view with some views to represent your cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the new [`UICollectionView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) added in iOS 6.0

It's pretty the same as a `UITableView` but it's easier for those "card-style" views.

Comment: Thanks. I'm new here but that's so I'm still getting know what are the rules. Sorry if the question was vague. Anyhow, I also just wanted to test if anybody would really answer my questions. Being a newbie, I didn't expect to get any response at all. So this is totally a surprise. The UICollectionView is what I'm looking for. Again, thanks to all to took time to respond.

Comment: With the ckeck mark you can accept an answer if it's correct ;-)